# Cuffon is undefined. Javascript error on IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, undefined

I am getting this error 'Cufon' is undefined on my blog http://microreviews.org The error comes on Line 20, char1.

I also get the error 'dtsv' is undefined on Line 57 and character 3.

The errors comes only on IE7 and IE6 and no other browser. I donot really care for IE6 but the error on IE 7 is a major source of concern. What can be done to get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening in other browsers too -- check your error console.

For "Cufon is undefined", it's line 20 - that line is:
"Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4 ,h5', { fontfamily: 'Museo Sans 500' });

So .. whatever "Cufon" is supposed to be - it's not defined.
I notice that there's a link just prior to this:
http://microreviews.org/wp-content/themes/kreativ/js/cufon-yui.js

Which is resolving to a 404 error (not found) -- so that's probably your problem.

The "dtsv is undefined" problem is the same thing.  Line 57:
dtsv.root = 'http://microreviews.org/wp....'

At that point, dtsv hasn't been initialized, so you can't set a property on it.

Answer (score 0):

cause your [Cufon file is not found](http://microreviews.org/wp-content/themes/kreativ/js/cufon-yui.js), check the url to your file. And what is dstv ???